# SSR relay module - AC switching only but need DC switching

Tags: solid-state-relay

I'm using an SSR module with a Raspberry Pi to control electromagnets (12V DC, each using 0.3A). I didn't realise the module is only for AC switching (the SSR is G3MB-202P), so it's not behaving as expected.

Would it be possible to remove the SSR and replace with one suitable for DC switching?

If not, can someone please advise about (or point me to) a schematic using other components which could replace each of the SSRs?

A photo of the module is attached.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I see some that look similar (rated at 2A/50 VDC) but you would have to unsolder the existing parts without damaging the board and replace it or them with the different SSR. I will not link them because there is not enough information to be sure they'll fit and be otherwise compatible.

You would also have to pay attention to polarity on the output and ensure that the fuse was still adequate.